# How can i beautify my code in Matlab (tabs, deleting unnecessary spaces etc.)?

Tags: matlab

i'm looking to find a way to beautify my code in MATLAB. I'm talking about tabs, deleting unnecessary spaces etc., the way Eclipse does it with Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: MATLAB has a tool to correct indentation, select your code and right-click. the pop-up menu has this option. It doesn't fix spacing or other things though.

Comment: To add to @CrisLuengo 's comment, the smart indent command also removes trailing white spaces. It is available both in the right-click pop-up menu, but also with a shortcut (default Ctrl+I).

Answer (score 2):

The [smart indentation](https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/05/11/keep-your-code-readable-with-smart-indenting/) (ctrl + I) is probably all you need (as @Matteo V and @Cris Luengo already mentioned).

However, there are a few other neat tricks that you might want to have a look at if you are really into code development:

- Well, first have a look at the [Improve Code Readability](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/improve-code-readability.html) site of MATLAB. You could use the *Apply smart indenting while typing* option in the *Preferences > MATLAB > Editor/Debugger > Language > Indenting* section (it should be turned on per default but I like the *Indent all functions* setting). There are a bunch of other settings that you may want to explore
- If you dig yourself deeper in the MATLAB IDE, you will notice that you can adjust almost everything to your preferences, but the way is not always documented in the web.... however, the local documentation (call `doc`) contains the info you may be looking for, see this [blog-post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/366464-documentation-of-editor-api)

I am not aware of an automatic detection of double spaces or similar but you might end up writing your own little callback-function. Most languages ignore this anyway (perhaps except for Python). Code readability is usually a topic that the programmer(s) should care about... and not the machines ;)

Further tips:

- respect the *Right-hand text limit*, which is the vertical gray line in your editor and shall indicate how many characters a single line of code should have as maximum. If it is a comment, wrap it. If it is an expression, try to outsource some commands to a dedicated variable
- use equally long variable names. (There is no style guide as in Python, which says that you should use normal words and underscores etc) E.g. if you have two variables describing a commanded and a measured velocity, you could call them `v_cmd` and `v_act` and your code perfectly aligns if you apply the same manipulations to both variables ;)
- use section. With `%%`  (the space is important) at the beginning of a line in the editor, you create a section (you'll note the slight yellow background color and the bold writing that follows this command). It is convenient to structure your code. You can even run entire sections *Editor*-Tab > *Run* > *Run section*
- Although there are programmers claiming that a good code speaks for itself (and therefore doesn't need any comments), to my experience writing comments has never been a bad idea. It improves the readability of your code

The answer might have been a bit elaborate for such an innocent question ... oO